# Bootstrap drowndown VS dynamic document height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

So I'm building a page using Bootstrap 4 Shards, with a number of dropdowns some of which are initially hidden with .d-none. The dropdowns are stacked vertically, so as you unhide more, the height of the entire document increases. Everything works fine except for the position of the dropdowns which is always limited to the initial viewport height, meaning that I can't get any dropdowns to display below where the browser window ends on page load. Any workaround (I'm using Popper, bootstrap.min and shards.min, nothing non-standard)?

Below is a sample row with dropdowns, and the problem appears when I have a number of these rows stacked vertically, afflicting the lower rows:

```
<div id="pair-1" class="row p-3 ml-2 mr-2 border-bottom ">
                            <div class="col-1 text-right mt-3">
                              Pair 1:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2 text-right">

                              <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg dropdown-toggle w-100" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                              Driver gear
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" x-placement="bottom-start"><a class="dropdown-item" href="1"><img src="images/gears/gear1.png" class="mr-2">1 tooth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="8"><img src="images/gears/gear8.png" class="mr-2">8 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="12"><img src="images/gears/gear12.png" class="mr-2">12 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="14"><img src="images/gears/gear14.png" class="mr-2">14 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="16"><img src="images/gears/gear16.png" class="mr-2">16 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="20"><img src="images/gears/gear20.png" class="mr-2">20 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="24"><img src="images/gears/gear24.png" class="mr-2">24 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="28"><img src="images/gears/gear28.png" class="mr-2">28 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="36"><img src="images/gears/gear36.png" class="mr-2">36 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="40"><img src="images/gears/gear40.png" class="mr-2">40 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="56"><img src="images/gears/gear56.png" class="mr-2">56 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="60"><img src="images/gears/gear60.png" class="mr-2">60 teeth</a></div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">

                              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg dropdown-toggle w-100" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                              Follower gear
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" x-placement="bottom-start"><a class="dropdown-item" href="8"><img src="images/gears/gear8.png" class="mr-2">8 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="12"><img src="images/gears/gear12.png" class="mr-2">12 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="14"><img src="images/gears/gear14.png" class="mr-2">14 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="16"><img src="images/gears/gear16.png" class="mr-2">16 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="20"><img src="images/gears/gear20.png" class="mr-2">20 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="24"><img src="images/gears/gear24.png" class="mr-2">24 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="28"><img src="images/gears/gear28.png" class="mr-2">28 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="36"><img src="images/gears/gear36.png" class="mr-2">36 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="40"><img src="images/gears/gear40.png" class="mr-2">40 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="56"><img src="images/gears/gear56.png" class="mr-2">56 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="60"><img src="images/gears/gear60.png" class="mr-2">60 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="60a"><img src="images/gears/gear60a.png" class="mr-2">60 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="140"><img src="images/gears/gear140.png" class="mr-2">140 teeth</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="168"><img src="images/gears/gear168.png" class="mr-2">168 teeth</a></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col align-middle"></div>
                          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dug a bit deeper and found a workaround: apparently adding

`data-display="static"`

to the button that calls the dropdown solves the issue.